# Is it possible to do a SaveAs of specific extensions using the Interface SaveAsCapable in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform, save-as

I am trying to port a java application into a netbeans platform application.

While trying to port the SaveAs action using the Interface SaveAsCapable, I found that there is no way to specify the extensions that I want to use to save the file.

The old application had a code similar to this:

```
            // Adds the default file format
            FileFilter defaultFilter = xmlPngFilter;
            fc.addChoosableFileFilter(defaultFilter);
            fc.addChoosableFileFilter(new DefaultFileFilter(".txt",
                    "Graph Drawing " + mxResources.get("file")
                            + " (.txt)"));
```

How can I do something similar to specify the file extensions with the SaveAsCapable interface:

http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-loaders/org/openide/loaders/SaveAsCapable.html#method_summary